# How i can get image id from ImageView?

Tags: java, android

Have code like this:

```
case R.id.button:
int id=randImage();
imgView1.setImageResource(id);
public int randImage() {
Random rand= new Random();
int randomNumber=rand.nextInt(24)+1;
String randomImage="img"+randomNumber;
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(randomImage, "drawable", getPackageName());
return id;

}
case R.id.imgView1:
Intent i= new Intent(); 
i.putExtra("imgId", id); //IS UNREACHABLE
```

How i can get drawable id after set ?

Comment: maybe you forgot the break; after the first case. Also the method declaration within a switch-case block is not valid java syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you can recover it after setting, but you can associate a tag with the component:

```
int id = randImage();
imgView1.setImageResource(id);
imgView1.setTag(id);
```

And when you need to get the id you simply:

```
int id = imgView1.getTag();
```

Answer (score 0):

Save it first:

```
int Id=randImage();
imgView1.setImageResource(Id);
```

Comment: Id is the ID of the resource (equivalent to the value of R.Drawable.imgxxxx)

Comment: I don't understand. You can save the Id in an ArrayList each time you set the image. Do you want to retreive it from another Class or what?

Comment: First of all, you should add a break after each Case

Comment: Then make Id a global variable